# Make tables related

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to design a database for my website but i have a little problem with making related tables .

I have two tables . Table1 and Table2

Table1 is used to store user`s information and Table2 is used to store their activation codes

To relate them i need to store each user's ID in Table1 , inside Each record of Table2 so that i can get my user`s activation code

And as i know it is how relational databases work.

My problem is when using php to run mysql commands and add new user information in Table1 , How can i find What ID Number will be assigned to my user so that i can save both Id and activation code in my other table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PDO, you can use the function `lastInsertId()` to retrieve the last id inserted in your last query.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

If you use Mysqli, you have the `mysqli_insert_id()` function .
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php